# ATG: Update Order Pattern

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, atg, oracle-commerce

It has been known that you must use the following pattern in order to update an order in ATG `Form-Handlers` that doesn't inherit from the **PurchaseProcessFormHanlder**:

```
boolean acquireLock = false;
ClientLockManager lockManager = getLocalLockManager();

try {
    acquireLock = !lockManager.hasWriteLock(profile.getRepositoryId(), Thread.currentThread());
    if (acquireLock) {
        lockManager.acquireWriteLock(profile.getRepositoryId(), Thread.currentThread());
    }

    boolean shouldRollback = false;

    TransactionDemarcation transactionDemarcation = new TransactionDemarcation();
    TransactionManager transactionManager = getTransactionManager();

    transactionDemarcation.begin(transactionManager, TransactionDemarcation.REQUIRED);

    try {
        synchronized (getOrder()) {
            ...
            ...
            ...
        }
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        shouldRollback = true;
        vlogError(ce, "There has been an exception during processing of order: {0}", getOrder().getId());
    } finally { 
        try {
            transactionDemarcation.end(shouldRollback);
        } catch (final TransactionDemarcationException tde) {
            vlogError(tde, "TransactionDemarcationException during finally: {0}", tde.getMessage());
        } finally {
            vlogDebug("Ending Transaction for orderId: {0}", order.getId());
        }
    }
} catch (final DeadlockException de) {
    vlogError(de, "There has been an exception during processing of order: {0}", order.getId());
} catch (final TransactionDemarcationException tde) {
    vlogError(tde, "There has been an exception during processing of order: {0}", order.getId());
} finally {
    try {
        if (acquireLock) {
            lockManager.releaseWriteLock(getOrder().getProfileId(), Thread.currentThread(), true);
        }
    } catch (final Throwable th) {
        vlogError(th, "There has been an error during release of write lock: {0}", th.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In theory, any `FormHandler` that inherits from the **PurchaseProcessFormHandler** already implements the following steps OOTB:

1. Acquire **LocalLockManager** in order to avoid concurrent threads to modify the same order:

   ```
   try {
       acquireLock = !lockManager.hasWriteLock(profile.getRepositoryId(), Thread.currentThread());
       if (acquireLock) {
           lockManager.acquireWriteLock(profile.getRepositoryId(), Thread.currentThread());
       }
   } catch (final DeadlockException de) {
       vlogError(de, "There has been an exception during processing of order: {0}", order.getId());
   }
   ```
2. Create a new **Transaction**:

   ```
   try {
       TransactionDemarcation transactionDemarcation = new TransactionDemarcation();
       TransactionManager transactionManager = getTransactionManager();

       transactionDemarcation.begin(transactionManager, TransactionDemarcation.REQUIRED);
   } catch (final TransactionDemarcationException tde) {
       vlogError(tde, "There has been an exception during processing of order: {0}", order.getId());
   }
   ```
3. **Ending the Transaction** being used:

   ```
   try {
       TransactionManager transactionManager = getTransactionManager();
       Transaction transaction = transactionManager.getTransaction();

       // If transaction is elegible for commiting: 
       transactionManager.commit();
       transaction.commit();

       // otherwise
       transactionManager.rollback();
       transaction.rollback();
   } catch (final Exception ex) {
       error = true;
       vlogError(ex, "There has been an exception during processing of order: {0}", order.getId());
   } finally {
       // handle the error
   }
   ```
4. **Release the lock** being used for the transaction:

   ```
   finally {
       ClientLockManager lockManager = getLocalLockManager();
       lockManager.releaseWriteLock(profile.getRepositoryId(), Thread.currentThread(), true);
   }
   ```

As per ATG documentation, the following methods implement the behaviour descripted above:

1. **Method**: beforeSet

   > Called before any setX methods on this form are set when a form that modifies properties of this form handler is submitted. Creates a transaction if necessary at the beginning of the form submission process, optionally obtaining a local lock to prevent multiple forms from creating transactions that may modify the same order.

   - **Steps**: 1 & 2
2. **Method**: afterSet

   > Called after any setX methods on this form are set when a form that modifies properties of this form handler is submitted. Commits or rolls back any transaction created in beforeSet, and releases any lock that was acquired at the time.

   - **Steps**: 3 & 4

Such as you will only have to handle the following procedures in order to update the order:

1. **Syncronize** the block of code that's going to be used for  `order updating` in order to avoid thread concurrency.

   ```
   synchronized (getOrder()) {
       ...
       ...
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Perform order **modifications**:

   ```
   synchronized (getOrder()) {
       getOrder().setXXX();
       getOrder().removeXXX();
   }
   ```
3. **Update the order** (`updateOrder` pipeline chain will be invoked):

   ```
   synchronized (getOrder()) {
       ...
       ...
       ...
       getOrderManager().updateOrder(order);
   }
   ```

This is pretty straightforward, unless you have to edit an order in any of the following scenarios:

- Form handlers or custom form handler that are not in the `PurchaseProcessFormHandler`'s hierachy.
- Helpers or Tools classes.
- Processors
- ATG REST Web Services
- &c

If so, you will have to implement the **Transactional Pattern** within your components.

### Questions!

- Is there any other pattern known to use instead of using the transactional pattern?
- Would it be possible to implement/override the `beforeSet` & `afterSet` methods in FormHandlers just the same way ATG does it in `PurchaseProcessFormHandler`
- Are you aware of any other approach?

Comment: Your code above appears to jump between acquiring a write lock for the order vs the profile.  The oracle recommendation is to acquire a lock against the profile.  More details can be found at https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1362812.1.  Why would you want to follow any other pattern other than the one which is prescribed by the vendor?

Comment: @bated: Thank you, I just updated the question with your notes, I was wondering if any one else has achieved another approach for this situation rather than just adding the blocks of code stated by Oracle.

Comment: No worries.  I also notice that your transaction rollback is within the try block which is not recommended as what happens if there is an exception?  The transaction rollback should be in the finally block, using a boolean which is set to true at the start of the try block, and only set to false at the end of the try block.  I see this often in ATG code and causes order corruption.

Answer (score 0):

The series of steps you have outlined above is the prescribed series of steps for updating an order.

Feel free to factor it out in any way you find useful. Just ensure that when you update an order, you, or your inherited code, have performed the requisite steps.

One common way that ATG does similar factoring is for a given method, say `X(...)`, you would have a `preX(...)`, `doX(...)`, and `postX(...)` method. You can create an abstract class with all your boilerplate code in the `preX()` and `postX()` methods, maybe even declared final, and have the `doX()` declared abstract. Your component then will inherit from the abstract class and must implement the `doX()` method. You may need to handle exceptions explicitly as well.

This is, essentially, what the standard form handlers do (under different names).

For example;

```
public final void X(...) {
  preX(...); // call the pre method

  try {
    doX(...); // call the do method
  } catch (XException xe) {
    // handle error
  }

  postX(...); // call the post method
}

protected final void preX(...) {
  // do everything you need to do before your customer code
}

protected final void postX(...) {
  // do everything you need to do after your customer code
}

protected abstract void doX(...) throws XException;
```

Another thing you could do, instead of inheriting from an abstract class, is to define an annotation that has all the boilerplate code.

A third thing you could do, in a similar way, but a lot harder to shoehorn into your ATG code, might be to define an aspect or a method invocation interceptor using third party frameworks.

However, once again, whatever you do, and however you do it, just ensure that you follow all the steps.

Comment: Why not use the framework which has these defined already?  This is precisely the kind of suggestion which makes maintaining/supporting/upgrading ATG even more difficult!